# pointer-array issue in a simple C code

Tags: c

I get a bad error when I put `name` as a char pointer.
It is fine when I put it as an array but the same situation is with `*p3` without problem.
Why do I get an error only for `name`? Even the initialization did not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int dex;
    const int k = 5;
    char *name;
    char *p3 = "happy world";
    char *list[k]={"kamy",
        "frank",
        "chris",
        "sara",
        "ricky"};

    scanf("%s",name);
    //or gets(name);
    printf("printed name is <%s>", name);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase your compiler warnings and it'll point out your error. `name` is an uninitialised pointer, so it could be pointing anywhere and trying to write to where it points will cause undefined behaviour and if you're lucky a seg fault.

Either declare `name` as an array, or initialise it using `malloc` to allocate a block of memory.

You should also use `fgets` over `scanf` with the `%s` specifier to avoid buffer overflows, or at least pass in a width specifier to `scanf` so you don't overflow the buffer. Note that if you use `fgets` it'll also store the `'\n'` in the buffer.

ie.

```
char name1[30];
char *name2 = malloc(30 * sizeof(*name2));

fgets(name1, 30, stdin); // TODO - check return values
scanf("%29s", name2); // 30 - 1
//...
free(name2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `name` first using `malloc`

```
name = malloc(20);
scanf("%19s", name);
```

And then when you're done you should free the memory allocated:

```
free(name);
```

Comment: char *name =(char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

Comment: @maziarparsaeian `sizeof(char)` is always one

Answer (score 0):

`p3[]` allocs memory automaticaly, `*p3` does not.

To use `*p3` you must user `malloc` function.

Comment: p3 is working fine ,the problem is getting a name

Comment: @maziarparsaeian yup, I did miss the point.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is able to fetch input from stdin and place it in a `char*` but it won't allocate memory for you.

Try with:

```
char name[64];
scanf("%s",name);
```

Mind that `char *name` doesn't initialize the memory for characters. You need either to use automatic allocation as with `char name[64]` or allocate it dynamically with `char *name = calloc(64, sizeof(char))`. If you choose the latter approach you also have to release the memory when you don't need it anymore with `free(name)`.

Comment: i know if i change it to array it works but why with that notation doesnt though it is fine with p3 if i write printf("\n p3 = [%s] \n",p3);

Answer (score 0):

You declare `name` as a pointer, but you never initialize it. This means that when you try to write to in in the `scanf` call you write to a seemingly random memory location. This is undefined behavior and will most definitely lead to weird things happening.

You should create an array to hold the string:

```
char name[32];
```

Also, to not write beyond the end of the string, you should probably change the `scanf` call to so it knows the length:

```
scanf("%31s", name);
```

If you are getting a line, you should use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

And as a little tip: Don't forget to check the values returned from the functions you call, they may fail!

Answer (score 0):

`name` has not been initialised to point to anything, and thus points at some random location in memory. Using it invokes undefined behaviour.

Either declare it as an array, or allocate some memory.

You shouldn't be passing `p3` into `scanf()` either, as it's been assigned to point to a static string.

And don't ever use `gets()`. Ever.